# PHP код не работает из формы, но работает вне формы

Tags: php, html

Сделал зависимые поля со списком, но если разместить эти поля в форме, то второе поле со списком не заполняется. Вне формы всё работает. Как сделать чтобы второе поле со списком заполнялось в форме?

```
    <div class="tb"><form><table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="col">Рецепт</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="77" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Категория</td>
      <td width="144" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Название</td>
      <td width="209" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Описание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
<?php
require('connect.php');
echo '<select name="category" id="category" class="StyleSelectBox" onchange="javascript:category(this.value);return false;">';
if($_POST["category"]*1)
    echo '<option value="0">- Категория -</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="0">- Категория -</option>';
$query = mysqli_query($link,'select * from category where level=1');
if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
    while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        if($_POST["category"] == $category["id_category"])
            echo '<option value="'.$category["id_category"].'" selected>'.$category["name"].'</option>';
        else 
            echo '<option value="'.$category["id_category"].'">'.$category["name"].'</option>';
echo '</select>';
echo '<br/><select name="category_2" id="category_2" class="StyleSelectBox"></select>';
?>
</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Добавить запись">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" id="submit3" value="Показать таблицу">
        <input name="submit5" type="submit" id="submit5" value="Отправить"></td>
      </tr>
  </table></form></div>
```

Сурс из браузер:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Кулинарная книга</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function category(category) {
if(category!=0)
    $("#category_2").load("category_get.php",{category_2:category});
    else
        $("#category_2").html("");
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.tb {
    clear: both;
}
.StyleSelectBox {
    width:200px;
    height:24px;
    font:14px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, Verdana;
    text-align:left;
    background:#fff;
    line-height:30px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border:1;
    zoom:1; }
    #selectBoxInfo{
    clear:left;
    padding:10px;
    font:16px "Tahoma";
    color:red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Кулинарная книга </h1>
<div class="tb">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" scope="col">Категория</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Название</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Номер род. кат.</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Уровень</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="category_name" type="text" id="category_name"></td>
        <td><input name="category_pid" type="text" id="category_pid"></td>
        <td><input name="category_level" type="text" id="category_level"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" formaction="category_add.php" value="Добавить запись">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" formaction="category_show.php" value="Показать таблицу"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="tb"><form><table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="col">Рецепт</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="77" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Категория</td>
      <td width="144" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Название</td>
      <td width="209" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Описание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
<select name="category" id="category" class="StyleSelectBox" onchange="javascript:category(this.value);return false;"><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>76</b><br />
<option value="0">- Категория -</option><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<option value="1">Супы</option><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<option value="2">Салаты</option></select><br/><select name="category_2" id="category_2" class="StyleSelectBox"></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Добавить запись">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" id="submit3" value="Показать таблицу">
        <input name="submit5" type="submit" id="submit5" value="Отправить"></td>
      </tr>
</table></form></div>
<div class="tb"><form><table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" scope="col">Метод приготовления</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Инвентарь</td>
    <td>Метод</td>
    <td>Номер род. кат.</td>
    <td>Уровень</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name='inv_name'><option>Кастрюля</option><option>Сковорода</option><option>Нож</option></select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="submit4" id="submit4" value="Добавить запись"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл category_get.php

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$pid=$_REQUEST["category_2"];
if($pid) {
    echo '<option value="0">- Выберите -</option>';
    $sql1="select * from category where pid={$pid}";
    $ds1=mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($ds1))
        while($category_2=mysqli_fetch_array($ds1))
            echo '<option value="'.$category_2["id_category"].'">'.$category_2["name"].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: А где тут форма? Приведите полностью код, который не работает

Comment: Если его засунуть в форму, то не работает.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, в школьную? Приведите кусок НЕРАБОТАЮЩЕГО кода целиком, иначе можно гадать до бесконечности

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе

Comment: предлагаю открыть html в виде сорца (ctrl+u в большинстве браузеров) и посмотреть, что там нагенерировало.

Comment: Так же существует поверие, что формы внутри таблицы запрещены. Врать не буду - не выяснял, так как без надобности, но возможно отсюда ноги растут. Попробуйте в качестве эксперимента вынуть все это из таблицы, но оставить в форме.

Comment: @unit "второе поле со списком не заполняется" - что это значит? Чем не заполняется? У Вас джаваскриптовая функция `category` его заполняет? Где эта функция?

Comment: @rjhdby - Поверие? Да это настоящий карго-культ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult .

Comment: @rjhdby по всякому перепробовал, дело не в таблице, а именно в форме.

Comment: @Igor  добавил полный код страницы, там есть скрипт.

Comment: @unit Очень хорошо. Чините ошибки: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>76</b><br />

Comment: @Igor не понимаю в чём ошибка

Comment: @unit - Ваша страница изначально генерится в ответ на запрос GET, соответственно, $_POST - пустой. `if (isset($_POST['category'])`

Comment: @Igor ошибки исчезли, но всё равно не работает в форме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: category is not a function

конфликт имен между js функцией и элементом `<select id="category" name="category" ...`.

```js
function categoryChange(aCategory) {console.log(window.category);
  if(aCategory != 0)
    $("#category_2").html(
      "<option value='1'>Test 1</option>" + 
      "<option value='2'>Test 2</option>" + 
      "<option value='3'>Test 3</option>"
    );
  else
    $("#category_2").html("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Кулинарная книга </h1>
<div class="tb">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" scope="col">Категория</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Название</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Номер род. кат.</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Уровень</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="category_name" type="text" id="category_name"></td>
        <td><input name="category_pid" type="text" id="category_pid"></td>
        <td><input name="category_level" type="text" id="category_level"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" formaction="category_add.php" value="Добавить запись">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" formaction="category_show.php" value="Показать таблицу"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="tb"><form><table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="col">Рецепт</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="77" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Категория</td>
      <td width="144" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Название</td>
      <td width="209" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Описание</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
<select name="category" id="category" class="StyleSelectBox" onchange="javascript:categoryChange(this.value);return false;">
<option value="0">- Категория -</option><br />
<option value="1">Супы</option><br />
<option value="2">Салаты</option></select><br/><select name="category_2" id="category_2" class="StyleSelectBox"></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Добавить запись">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" id="submit3" value="Показать таблицу">
        <input name="submit5" type="submit" id="submit5" value="Отправить"></td>
      </tr>
</table></form></div>
<div class="tb"><form><table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" scope="col">Метод приготовления</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Инвентарь</td>
    <td>Метод</td>
    <td>Номер род. кат.</td>
    <td>Уровень</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name='inv_name'><option>Кастрюля</option><option>Сковорода</option><option>Нож</option></select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="submit4" id="submit4" value="Добавить запись"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></div>
```

Comment: Исправил название, ошибка прежняя: TypeError: category is not a function

Comment: Всё поправил благодаря вам. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Собственно смотрите, что у вас в index.php в строках 76 и 83

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>76</b><br />
<option value="0">- Категория -</option><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<option value="1">Супы</option><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: category in <b>X:\xampp\htdocs\cookbook\index.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
```

Comment: Да, дело в этом. Что ему не нравится в индексе?

Comment: Исправил, убрал вообще эти строчки и ошибок нет, но всё по прежнему - в форме не работает, вне формы работает.

Comment: @unit Откройте Developers Tools в браузере и посмотрите ошибки в консоли.

Comment: @Igor TypeError: category is not a function